# What is a good book to learn all of prealgebra?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am an old man trying to learn mathematics, starting off with prealgebra and need a good comprehensive book for it. The book should NOT contain annoying images like in most American textbooks or anything irritating, just serious math. It should be rigorous, comprehensive and above all; serious.

Answer (score 1):

I find this book to be very intuitive and most important of all , it is comprehensive.

[The Art of problem solving](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934124214)

It is really worth reading as it changes and simplifies things really well.

It is also an excellent preparation for a course like Number theory or  statistics.

Comment: I hope you don't mind this, but I am very poor and I can't seem to find a PDF for that online. I have searched everywhere and would love to have that book. Is there any way to pirate it?

Comment: I also don't find a pdf version of it, You can check libgen.org

Comment: @JesusChrist The opinion on meta.math.stackexchange is that we should not encourage piracy of books.  See posts [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-the-policy-regarding-mentioning-that-a-book-is-available-to-download-via/1245) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/requests-for-electronic-versions-of-books) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/529/to-what-extent-should-copyrighted-material-be-made-available-on-math-se).  That being said, I was able to find a copy within a minute, you just haven't looked in the right places.

Comment: I have checked Library Genesis for it and still couldn't find anything on it, I would love to have any version of that book, whether it be an epub, pdf, djvu or even an mobi. Hope somebody helps out here...

Comment: JMoravitz, I don't know where you searched but I have literally searched everywhere for "Prealgebra" in the Art of Problem Solving series and couldn't find it. Can you please share the link for it? I would really really really appreciate it.

Comment: @JesusChrist No I will not, again citing the reason that doing so would be frowned upon (as per the consensus in the meta discussions on the matter in the aforementioned posts).  I don't mean to sound like a social darwinist, but if a \$30 book will make or break your bank account, then perhaps you should have higher priorities.  Perhaps you could request it from your local public library or local college library.

Comment: Oh man, the AoPS problem solving books are THE best. They have changed my life. Unfortunately, they are actually pretty expensive, but if you save up enough money, every cent is worth it.

Comment: look here :  https://sites.google.com/a/corvallis.k12.or.us/mrs-mulligan-s-web-page/pre-algebra-book

Comment: Videos are moving pictures, but if you don't mind that then there are lots of pre-algebra courses on Coursera, for example.

Comment: There a lof of math books (in russian language) on the internet and free,but almost all enhlish books are on the sale